# Giving unique id to each item in `ng-repeat` for DOM manipulations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
.div(ng-repeat='item in items') 
   button(id='ID{{$index}}') No Hi

button(id='anotherID1') Hi
```

inside relevant Angular Directive

```
$('#ID1').on('click', function() {alert('hi');});  // does not work 

$('#anotherID1').on('click', function() {alert('hi');}); // works
```

I am performing DOM manipulations for which i need unique ID for ng-repeat elements. Please also suggest if DOM manipulation can be performed in any other way too.

Edit: @tymeJV:-

```
 style.
  .ques {
    height: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }



<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <div class='ques'> {{item.ques}}
    </div>
    <button id='ID{{$index}}'> No Hi </button>
</div>
```

// Directive Code:- to increase height of `<div class = 'ques'>`

Comment: just to know : what is your tempmlate engine : jade ?

Comment: What is the final html generated. How does the id property look in it?

Comment: Use directives for DOM manipulation please! jQuery style click handlers are not very Angular-y.

Comment: @Chandermani angular does not recognize `ID1` which is generated thru  `ID{{$index}}` so no effect of the former statement

Comment: @tymeJV i am using directives. the above code is part of the directive only. However there is `jQuery` in it. If u can suggest alternative code. please do.

Comment: @SangramSingh -- Well, what is the main reason you even want to use ID's? Could this be solved by just using an instance of `this`?

Comment: @tymeJV no. I'm making an edit, to show the usecase.

Comment: @SangramSingh -- How about the actual Angular `.directive`?

Comment: There is no point writing the actual directive, when even a simple `alert('hi')` does not work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you are using Angular, it is recommended that you stick with standard Angular directives for listeners rather than reverting to jQuery. So instead of jQuery's `on`, use the `ng-click` attribute on HTML events you want Angular to bind a listener to.

For example:

**HTML**:

```
<button ng-click="doStuff()">
</button>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.doStuff = function () {
    //perform action
};
```

For storing a unique ID with each element created by `ng-repeat`, how about adding a parameter to the `doStuff` call with the ID: `ng-click="doStuff(item.ID)"` and access it in the `$scope.doStuff` method.

Comment: For DOM manipulation, Directives are recommended over Controllers. $scope.doStuff = function () {
    //perform action
}; is part of Controller code, whereas i'm trying to get it done thru Directives.

Answer (score 3):

id={{'flowchartWindow'+$index}} this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    button(id={{'ID'+$index}})

Answer (score -4):

For dynamically allocated id. the syntax of `$('#ID1').on('click', function() {alert('hi');});` changes a bit to

```
$('#YourWrapperID').on('click','#id1' , function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

Works perfectly!